# Access hidden property in base class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, polymorphism

In my ASP.NET Core API, I have a DTO class `BaseDto` and another `DerivedDto` that inherits from `BaseDto` and hides some of its properties, because they're required in `DerivedDto`. I also have a `BaseModel` class to which both `BaseDto` and `DerivedDto` will be mapped through another class `Mapper`.

Something like the following code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedDto : BaseDto
{
    [Required]
    public new string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public string NameModel { get; set; }
}

public static class Mapper
{

    public static BaseModel MapToModel(BaseDto dto) => new BaseModel
    {
        NameModel = dto.Name
    };
}
```

But it turns out, when passing a `DerivedDto` object to the `MapToModel` method, it's trying to access the values of the `BaseDto` (which are `null`) instead of the `DerivedDto` ones.

Is there any way I can achieve this behavior?

I can only think of declaring `BaseDto` as abstract, but that would prevent me from instantiating it, which I need to do.

Comment: virtual (in base) + override (in derived)? eventualy base call `get { return base.Name } set { base.Name = value }`

Comment: Hidning means effectivly that member is only accessable on a reference of the derived type. In your case the reference is of type `BaseDto`, which has no clew on the `new` member and thus just calls into its own implementaion. You may create another overload of `MapTo` that excepts a `DerivedDto`, but that´s really oggy - but that is `new` all about. However chances are high you don´t actually need to hide the property, just set another value within the derived constructor.

Comment: @Selvin You seem right. I don't think I need to overwrite the get and set methods, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your BaseDto class property as virtual and then override it in the DerivedDto class as follows:

```
public class BaseDto
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedDto : BaseDto
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also, please fix your Mapper class method. There is no property Name in the BaseModel. It needs to be "NameModel = dto.Name"

Comment: Edited, thanks. Your answer does seem to be correct. Unfortunately, my problem seems more complex than I described. Instead of the string Name property, I have a reference to another class, which will also derive from another base class (because of required properties). But, that should be another question entirely, I guess. I'll be accepting your answer later