# Access hidden property through base class c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

In my ASP.NET Core API, I have a DTO class `BaseBDto` and another `DerivedBDto` that inherits from it, and hides some of its properties, because they're required in `DerivedBDto`. The properties of `BaseBDto` and `DerivedBDto` are objects of another classes, `BaseADto` and `DerivedADto` respectively, that follow the same logic as the first ones.  I also have a `BaseModel` class to which both `BaseBDto` and `DerivedBDto` will be mapped through another class `Mapper`.

Something like the following code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class BaseADto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedADto : BaseADto
{
    [Required]
    public new string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseBDto
{
    public BaseADto A { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedBDto : BaseBDto
{
    [Required]
    public new DerivedADto A { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public string NameModel { get; set; }
}

public static class Mapper
{
    public static BaseModel MapToModel(BaseBDto dto) => new BaseModel
    {
        NameModel = dto.A.Name
    };
}
```

But it turns out, when passing a `DerivedBDto` object to the `MapToModel` method, it's trying to access the values of the `BaseBDto` (which are `null`) instead of the `DerivedBDto` ones.

Is there any way I can achieve this behavior?

I can only think of declaring `BaseBDto` as abstract, but that would prevent me from instantiating it, which I need to do.

PS: I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840471/access-hidden-property-in-base-class-c-sharp), but I oversimplified my code sample, so I felt another question was necessary.
Also, the solution provided there doesn't work because I can't override the A property at `DerivedBDto` with a `DerivedADto` since it must have the same type as the A property at `BaseBDto`.

Comment: As the answer in your other question suggested, you need to use virtual and override.  Hiding properties only works if nothing ever accesses it as the base class, but if you pass the object as the base class it will use the hidden property and not the hiding property.  Virtual and Override are what you want to solve that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access hidden property in base class c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840471/access-hidden-property-in-base-class-c-sharp)

Comment: In the future, consider editing your existing question.  No need to create a duplicate.

Comment: @Tarazed I don't think this question is a duplicate of my original one. Like I said, I oversimplified my code example in the other question. Also, the solution doesn't work in this particular case, because I can't override a property with a type derived of the original property's type. See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIHkAR) and uncomment the `virtual` and `override` keywords to toggle the compilation erros.

Comment: If your return type is different you shouldn't be hiding anything, you should consider using a different name.  At that point it's a completely different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `MapToModel` signature to be generic. The below

```
public static BaseModel MapToModel<T>(T dto) where T : BaseBDto => new BaseModel
{
    NameModel = dto.A.Name
};
```

Comment: This produces the same behavior as my version of the `MapToModel` method.